# How to relocate the node in jstree after dragging back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jstree

Suppose we have two trees with the following structure:

tree #1:

- root
  - child #1-1

    - child #1-1-1
  - child #1-2

tree #2:

- root
  - child #2-1

    - child #2-1-1
  - child #2-2

now we drag the child #1-1-1 from tree one underneath child #2-1-1 in tree two, what should we do to force the child #1-1-1 place into its original location(regardless of it's dropped location) after dragging back to its own tree?

Comment: Can tree #1 change state while #1-1-1 is missing? What if you removed #1-1 while #1-1-1 is not in #1?

Comment: Actually No, The nodes can't be removed, they only transfer between trees.